# Javascript : Cant get divs to align properly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, cytoscape.js

I am trying to create the charts displayed in

https://gist.github.com/maxkfranz/eb861f83fb741628342f

so basically, i have a bootstrap container and

```
<div class="container">

    /*Other divs here*/

    <div id="cy" style=" height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #FAEDEF;"></div>

                <div id="cy2" style=" height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: #EDF1FA;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;"></div>
</div>
```

and here are my head elements

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api/cytoscape.js-latest/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
```

and here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var elesJson = {
  nodes: [
    { data: { id: 'a', foo: 3, bar: 5, baz: 7 } },
    { data: { id: 'b', foo: 7, bar: 1, baz: 3 } },
    { data: { id: 'c', foo: 2, bar: 7, baz: 6 } },
    { data: { id: 'd', foo: 9, bar: 5, baz: 2 } },
    { data: { id: 'e', foo: 2, bar: 4, baz: 5 } }
  ], 

  edges: [
    { data: { id: 'ae', weight: 1, source: 'a', target: 'e' } },
    { data: { id: 'ab', weight: 3, source: 'a', target: 'b' } },
    { data: { id: 'be', weight: 4, source: 'b', target: 'e' } },
    { data: { id: 'bc', weight: 5, source: 'b', target: 'c' } },
    { data: { id: 'ce', weight: 6, source: 'c', target: 'e' } },
    { data: { id: 'cd', weight: 2, source: 'c', target: 'd' } },
    { data: { id: 'de', weight: 7, source: 'd', target: 'e' } }
  ]
};

$('#cy').cytoscape({
  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector('node')
      .css({
        'background-color': '#B3767E',
        'width': 'mapData(baz, 0, 10, 10, 40)',
        'height': 'mapData(baz, 0, 10, 10, 40)',
        'content': 'data(id)'
      })
    .selector('edge')
      .css({
        'line-color': '#F2B1BA',
        'target-arrow-color': '#F2B1BA',
        'width': 2,
        'target-arrow-shape': 'circle',
        'opacity': 0.8
      })
    .selector(':selected')
      .css({
        'background-color': 'black',
        'line-color': 'black',
        'target-arrow-color': 'black',
        'source-arrow-color': 'black',
        'opacity': 1
      })
    .selector('.faded')
      .css({
        'opacity': 0.25,
        'text-opacity': 0
      }),

  elements: elesJson,

  layout: {
    name: 'circle',
    padding: 10
  },

  ready: function(){

  }
});

$('#cy2').cytoscape({
  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector('node')
      .css({
        'background-color': '#6272A3',
        'shape': 'rectangle',
        'width': 'mapData(foo, 0, 10, 10, 30)',
        'height': 'mapData(bar, 0, 10, 10, 50)',
        'content': 'data(id)'
      })
    .selector('edge')
      .css({
        'width': 'mapData(weight, 0, 10, 3, 9)',
        'line-color': '#B1C1F2',
        'target-arrow-color': '#B1C1F2',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
        'opacity': 0.8
      })
    .selector(':selected')
      .css({
        'background-color': 'black',
        'line-color': 'black',
        'target-arrow-color': 'black',
        'source-arrow-color': 'black',
        'opacity': 1
      }),

  elements: elesJson,

  layout: {
    name: 'breadthfirst',
    directed: true,
    padding: 10
  },

  ready: function(){
    // ready 2
  }
});
  });
```

the problem is that when i open up the page, the two divs`cy` and `cy2` cover up the entire page! meaning all the other divs are overwritten.

Does this have something to do with `posiiton:absolute`? i tried to change it to relative, but if i do that then `cy` and `cy2` just appear as very thin lines!

I am new to css and i dont know how to configure the style so that the charts appear properly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Er... `width: 100%` means, cover up the whole width, right?

Comment: i even tried enclosing the divs inside a bootstrap grid, but still they cover up the entire page

Comment: Get rid of `width: 100%` also, `position: absolute` is a crazy weapon. Need to handle it carefully. What are you expecting to do?

Comment: i just want the two charts to show up and not cover the entire page

Comment: Change `width: 100%` to `width: 50%`? Try it for both and tell me.

Comment: Looks like this for me: http://output.jsbin.com/pemobacoce What you wanna do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `height: 50%`, but there's nothing for it to be 50% of. When you set the divs to `position: absolute`, they're getting 50% of the window height. If you can set a fixed height for them, you should be all set.

```
 <div id="cy" style="height: 400px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #FAEDEF;"></div>

 <div id="cy2" style=" height: 400px;
   background-color: #EDF1FA;
   border-top: 1px solid #ccc;"></div>
```